# FireBreath: Where should I modify global variables in config.h

Tags: firebreath

I am wondering where the variables in

```
firebreath\build\{ProjectDir}\gen\global\config.h
```

should be modified best. I want to increase for example

```
#define FBSTRING_PLUGIN_VERSION "1.0.0.0"
```

But when I do this in the file directly, it is going to be overwritten next time I modify

```
my_WiXInstall/Sources/myInstaller.wxs (in VC++ 2010)
```

and build the WiX-project, because then all templated files are being re-build again (including config.h).

How is this done correctly? Do I use the wrong config.h or is it wrong to modify the mentioned wxs-file. Of course I could modify the "Generated" wxs-file, but that would mean keeping track of the version numbers in it by myself. That feels wrong too.

I am confused. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer by myself: The variables/makros should be changed in

```
\firebreath\projects\{ProjectDir}\PluginConfig.cmake
```

They will then be distributed through the templates into all related files of the project.

Comment: Note that your project directory is not always in the firebreath root; that's where it is generated, but it's recommended to move it out for easier source control integration